# Cannot input text or Press Keys or Press Keycode

Tags: robotframework, appium-android

I am very new to robot framework, working it at pycharm.
I just want to input some text at current field. but none of these works.
I have tried

```
Press Keycode  a
Press Keys     text_field       q
input text      ${mylocator}     ${string-abc}


If I am using the correct library?

        *** Settings ***
        Library  AppiumLibrary  run_on_failure=AppiumLibrary.CapturePageScreenshot
        Library      Selenium2Library   run_on_failure=AppiumLibrary.CapturePageScreenshot
    
       *** Variables ***
       ${MsgEditor}     //*[@class='android.widget.RelativeLayout' and @resource-id='com.test.abc.work.cac:id/editor']
    
    *** Test Cases ***
    Add item
         Press Keys    text_field     q <--error browser not open
        \\or
        appiumlibrary.Input Text    ${MsgEditor}    update <== error Message: Cannot set the element to 'update'. Did you interact with the correct element?
```

updated that Press Keys still failed. error:

```
KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Press Keys text_field, q
Documentation:  
Simulates the user pressing key(s) to an element or on the active browser.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20201218 10:05:20.575 / 20201218 10:05:21.339 / 00:00:00.764
00:00:00.755KEYWORD AppiumLibrary . Capture Page Screenshot
10:05:20.575    TRACE   Arguments: [ 'text_field' | 'q' ]   
10:05:20.581    INFO    Sending key(s) ('q',) to text_field element.    
10:05:21.339    FAIL    No browser is open. 
10:05:21.339    DEBUG   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\tester\pycharmprojects\androidtest\venv\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\__init__.py", line 471, in run_keyword
    return DynamicCore.run_keyword(self, name, args, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\tester\pycharmprojects\androidtest\venv\lib\site-packages\robotlibcore.py", line 103, in run_keyword
    return self.keywords[name](*args, **(kwargs or {}))
  File "c:\users\tester\pycharmprojects\androidtest\venv\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\keywords\element.py", line 895, in press_keys
    element = self.find_element(locator)
  File "c:\users\tester\pycharmprojects\androidtest\venv\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\base\context.py", line 74, in find_element
    return self.element_finder.find(locator, tag, True, required, parent)
  File "c:\users\tester\pycharmprojects\androidtest\venv\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\locators\elementfinder.py", line 74, in find
    parent=parent or self.driver)
  File "c:\users\tester\pycharmprojects\androidtest\venv\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\base\context.py", line 32, in driver
    return self.ctx.driver
  File "c:\users\tester\pycharmprojects\androidtest\venv\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\__init__.py", line 547, in driver
    raise NoOpenBrowser('No browser is open.')
```

InputText failed. I have this same InputText at other field and works. I tried tap over different field with that locator and it works.
is the app has issue on that element? but i can press on keyboard manually after tap to the field.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading the official documentation first: http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html and the user guide as well: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html

`Press Keys` is not a keyword from AppiumLibrary. It's a keyword from SeleniumLibrary (https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys), but you're not importing it to your project. And even if you imported it, this keyword takes two arguments (locator and keys), so you need to use it correctly.

```
*** Test Cases ***
     Press Keys     a
```

In addition to what I've said, there's no test case name, this is incorrect and won't work, it will in fact give you the following error:

> Test case name cannot be empty.

You have correctly used [Input Test](http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Input%20Text) keyword from AppiumLibrary. However, you might need to validate that your locator is correct. We can't say that since you didn't include that information in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry I just cut partial of test case. The test case name is there. No issue on that.

Comment: Also the locator is correct as I can use tap into it. Just that press key doesn't work. I don't see any key inserted.

Comment: Okay I saw the mistake at a press Keys, I need to have text_field then followed by value.

Comment: i just tried Press Keys and error on browser not open.

Answer (score 0):

I have used another method. Adb shell input text to fire the text

Comment: Can you offer a concrete example of the shell command you used?